# Как изменить кодировку поля в ms sql на лету

Tags: sql, кодировка

Помогите пож изменить кодировку. Есть запрос типа:

```
var insertToTemp = SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand(string.Format(
    @"insert into {0}(X, Y)
    select Description as X, ID as Y
    from  Table)", tempTable)).ExecNonQuery();
```

он выполняется и работает, но закачивает абракадабру в Y. 
tempTable.Y (типы полей tempTable.Y и Table.ID стоит ColumnType.Char, 254)
Как можно изменить кодировку для Y на лету?

ID выглядит так https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0rXx.png
а при insert получаю в таком виде https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nljk4.png

Comment: Доплните вопрос минимальным примером данных, тяжело сказать чо вы храните и пробуете записать

Comment: типы полей `tempTable.Y` и `Table.ID`?

Comment: стоит ColumnType.Char, 254 для обоих

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос определения обеих таблиц.